# How do I query/filter a to-many relationship in Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have Customer, Event and Address objects in my data model.  Both Customer and Address have a one-to-many relationship to Event.

I can get the distinct list of addresses for a customer's events for by doing this:

```
NSSet *addressSet = [customer valueForKeyPath:@"events.address"];
```

For the part of the UI I'm working on now, I need to display the address from the most recent event prior to now that has an address.

I'm starting to go down the path of creating a NSFetchRequest, setting it's entity, sort descriptors, predicate and then looping through the results, but it seems like a lot of code.  Am I missing some obvious way of filtering/sorting on the "events" relationship of the Customer object or is creating the NSFetchRequest the best solution?

Comment: It helps to accept the answer (if you feel it is right :) so that it can increase your reputation on here for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple because of the KVO and KVC accessors that are available on `NSSet` and `NSArray`.

```
NSSet *eventsWithAddress = [[customer valueForKey:@"events"] filteredSetWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"address != nil"]];
id mostRecentEvent = [eventsWithAddress valueForKeyPath:@"@max.lastDate"];
```

Of course the property name is up to you since I cannot see your data model but that gives you a general idea of where the code needs to go.  You can see what operators are available in Apple's documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html

**WARNING:** Code written in StackOverflow comment window so you will most likely need to tweak it a bit.

Comment: Thanks, that put me on the right track.  I'd forgotten about filteredSetUsingPredicate.  All I needed to add to your code was lastDate being less than the current date/time.